# Wrong order of GraphQL resolver arguments (root, args, context)

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I'm wondering why my arguments seem to be switched around inside my GraphQL resolver. I'm using express-graphql.

Example of one resolver:

```
  getLocalDrivers: async (parent, args, ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx);
  }
```

I've written the argument names as they appear in the docs: http://graphql.org/learn/execution/

But when I debug and inspect the objects, it seems the args object is 1st, the context is 2nd, and the parent/root is 3rd.

parent:

```
Object {location: "020202"}
```

args:

```
IncomingMessage {_readableState: ReadableState, readable: false, domain: null, …}
```

context:

```
Object {fieldName: "getLocalDrivers", fieldNodes: ....
```

Some server code:

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
    rootValue: rootResolver
  })
);
```

My rootResolver:

```
var rootResolver = {
     getLocalDrivers: async (obj, args, ctx) => {
       console.log(ctx);
  }
}
```

Schema:

```
var { buildSchema } = require("graphql");
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    getLocalDrivers(location: String): [Driver]
  }

  type Driver {
    name: String
    location: String    
  }`);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `resolve` function is defined for a field, when GraphQL resolves that field, it will pass **four** parameters to that function:

1. the value the parent field resolved to (commonly referred to as `obj` or `root`)
2. the arguments for that field
3. the context
4. an info object that describes the entire GraphQL request

If a resolve function is absent for a particular field, GraphQL will utilize the default resolver, which simply searches for a property on the parent field and uses that if it's found.

So your `getLocalDrivers` query could return an array of `Driver` objects, and as long as the `Driver` object has a `name` property, the `name` *field* will resolve to that property's value.

Coincidentally, the `name` property on that `Driver` object could also be a function. In that case, GraphQL would call that function to get its return value. And very much like a resolver, GraphQL passes some information to this function as parameters, namely 1) the arguments, 2) the context and 3) the info object. When fields are resolved in this way, the "obj" parameter is omitted.

**Ok, so what about the root?**

The root object is just the object that serves as the "parent field value" that's given to queries and mutations, which are fields like everything else.

So, if you haven't defined a "resolve" function for `getLocalDrivers` (because you compiled you schema with `buildQuery` for example), GraphQL will utilize the default resolver, and use the root object you passed in as the "parent field value". It sees a `getLocalDrivers`, but as described above, because this a function, it calls that function with the above-mentioned three parameters.

**So what's the lesson here?**

Don't use root.

Seriously. Either define your schema as an object, or if you want to write the schema out using GraphQL schema language, use [graphql-tools](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html) -- `makeExecutableSchema` makes dealing with resolvers much much easier.

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    getLocalDrivers(location: String): [Driver]
  }

  type Driver {
    name: String
    location: String    
  }
`
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getLocalDrivers: (obj, args, ctx) => {
       console.log({obj, args, ctx})
    }
  }
}
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting same results if I use `makeExecuteSchema` from graphql-tools instead of `buildSchema`.

Comment: If you're still passing in a root value then you will still see the same behavior. Pass in the resolvers as part of the resolvers object instead. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I simply made new server this time using Apollo GraphQL server instead, and started using makeExecuteableSchema to make it work. My end solution though has been to switch to Express REST for now as GraphQL is giving me too much issues :-)